# new wildcard certificate if I already own another certificate for a subdomain

Tags: certificates, wildcard

I already own a certificate for a subdomain `sub1.domain.com` but I would like to secure all subdomains of `domain.com` buying a wildcard certificate.
Can I still use the specific certificate for `sub1.domain.com` (so it works like an override of the wildcard certificate, like a wildcard DNS record) or I am required to install on that subdomain an instance of the new wildcard certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason you can not use both certificates.

However take note that a wildcard certificate is only valid for a single leaf (so something.example.com and not invalid.something.example.com)

the 2 certificates are completely independent of each other.
It is even possible (although that would break CA guidelines) to issue multiple certificates for the same FQDN.